# Django: Country drop down list?

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, django-forms, country, django-widget

I have a form for address information.  One of the fields is for the address country.  Currently this is just a textbox.  I would like a drop down list (of ISO 3166 countries) for this.  I'm a django newbie so I haven't even used a Django Select widget yet.  What is a good way to do this?

Hard-code the choices in a file somewhere?  Put them in the database?  In the template?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Django Countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries)

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class Foo(models.Model):
    country = CountryField()
```

Comment: @monokrome So what you're saying is that I'm right, and you need to do extra work to represent the country name in any other format.

Comment: For some reason, that import didn't work form me. I use `from django_countries.fields import CountryField`.

Comment: @JohnLehmann maybe it's changed, this is 5 years old. Updated.

Answer (score 35):

Check out "[choices](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices)" parameter of a CharField.

You might also want to take a look at [django-countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/).

Comment: Note that there are two django-countries projects. The one linked has much more comprehensive data, but appears not to be actively maintained, so watch out for out-of-date data.

Comment: Seems to be living on github now: https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/

Comment: @creimers Thanks! Updated accordingly.

Comment: Instead of the additional `django-countries` dependency, you could use `pytz`, which is already included with Django. See example [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62471903).

Answer (score 11):

Ended up using the below snippet which basically defines a tuple of tuples of two character country codes.  Additionally it defines a custom field type called CountryField and defaults the choices parameter to the above defined tuple.  This automatically gets rendered as a drop down list.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/494/

Comment: django-countries provides exactly the same. Its a reusable component.

Comment: Someone in the comment at djangosnippets recommends using this snippet instead: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1476/ It is more up to date and fixes the `maxlength` bug.

Answer (score 8):

Django Countries

```
from django_countries.countries import COUNTRIES

class CountryForm(forms.Form):
      country= forms.ChoiceField(COUNTRIES)
```

Comment: django-countries has a CountryField class now.

Comment: hi..there is one problem, when this form is rendered, by defaul it shows 'Afghanistan', which is the first country in the choice set of course..but what if the country field is not required? meaning, by default shows ---- or similar

Comment: The import location seems to have changed it's now ```from django_countries import countries```

Comment: Official documentation for using django_countries in a forms.Form: https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries#custom-forms

Answer (score 5):

Two low mantained projects:

http://code.google.com/p/django-countries/

https://github.com/strange/django-country-utils

Two snippets:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/494/

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1476/

For now, I am going for a snippet.

Answer (score 5):

As previous answers have stated, there is a `CountryField` in `django-countries`. This is a model field.

If a form field is needed in a plain form (not model form), in `django-countries` v3.x (definitely tested in 3.3) the following can be used:

```
from django_countries.data import COUNTRIES

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(sorted(COUNTRIES.items()))
```

Comment: This is helpful while creating a form with django-countries. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

#### UPDATE (Django >=4.0)

Using `pytz.country_names` was convenient in older Django versions, as described below, but Django >=4.0 uses `zoneinfo` instead of `pytz`. Details in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/4.0/#zoneinfo-default-timezone-implementation) and [here](https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Unfortunately, `zoneinfo` does not appear to offer an equivalent of `pytz.country_names` (as far as I know).

There is, however, an up-to-date list of ISO 3166 country names in Python's (first-party) [`tzdata`](https://tzdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package: [iso3166.tab](https://github.com/python/tzdata/blob/2023.3/src/tzdata/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab)

Note that `tzdata` is [already installed](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5e98959d9242c57a55c65847758781f82d386fa4/setup.cfg#L42) if you're using Django 4+ on Windows.

For illustrative purposes only, here's a quick & dirty way to parse the iso3166.tab file into a `dict` similar to `pytz.country_names` (Python 3.9+):

```py
from importlib import resources

with resources.files('tzdata.zoneinfo').joinpath('iso3166.tab').open('r') as f:
    country_names = dict(
        line.rstrip('\n').split('\t', 1)
        for line in f
        if not line.startswith('#')
    )
```

Note, for Django's field `choices`, it would be easier to create a `list` directly, instead of a `dict`.

#### ORIGINAL (Django <4.0)

Django (<4.0) uses `pytz` (see e.g. [django.utils.timezone](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/utils/timezone.py#L9)), and `pytz` exposes a `country_names` dictionary, based on ISO 3166 ([see pytz docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#country-information)).

This `pytz.country_names` dictionary can be used to set your [model field choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices), or [form field choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/).

This might not cover all edge cases, but, at least, it does not add another obscure external dependency to your Django project.

Example for a model field (`import pytz` first):

```
country = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=pytz.country_names.items())
```

Note that the dict keys (country codes) are all capitals.

One other thing to keep in mind, in case `pytz` is updated: as mentioned in the Django [Model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices)

> A new migration is created each time the order of `choices` changes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice library with countries (and not only): [pycountry](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry)

Its main advantage is that it is a wrapper around  Debian package pkg-isocodes (thus can updates automatically with it) compared to hard-coded countries in other solutions. It also has translations.

So if new country appears or existing countries will be merged together you do not need to change your code.

I found it useful to use this library and create a simple Django app with model Country for example

Then you can populate and keep up-to-date your 'country' table by means of custom django-admin command as described here: [Writing custom django-admin commands](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 1):

Put them in the database is a better way. Convenient to management.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `multiple=True`:

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField    

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    countries = CountryField(multiple=True)
```

You can read more about it in the docs:

https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries

Answer (score 1):

Link to package : [django-countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries)
If looking for how to do it in forms :

```
$ pip install django-countries

>>> from django_countries.data import COUNTRIES

>>> Country = forms.ChoiceField(choices = sorted(COUNTRIES.items()))
```

Comment: consider adding a link to the package

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have a country ChoiceField without installing [django-choices](https://pypi.org/project/django-countries/) you can create an extra file which holds a tuple with all choices from the [Wikipedia Iso Country Codes](http://geohack.net/gis/wikipedia-iso-country-codes.csv):

```
import csv


# Get the file from: "http://geohack.net/gis/wikipedia-iso-country-codes.csv"
with open("wikipedia-iso-country-codes.csv") as f:
    file = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    country_names = [line['English short name lower case'] for line in file]

# Create a tuple with the country names
with open("country_names.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write('COUNTRY_CHOICES = (\n')
    for c in country_names:
        f.write(f'    ("{c}", "{c}"),\n')
    f.write(')')
```

The created country_names.py file looks something like this:

```
COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
    ("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"),
    ("Åland Islands", "Åland Islands"),
    ("Albania", "Albania"),
    ("Algeria", "Algeria"),
    ("American Samoa", "American Samoa"),
    ...
)
```

You can then use COUNTRY_CHOICES in your form like this:

```
from django import forms
from country_names import COUNTRY_CHOICES


class CountryForm(forms.Form):
    country= forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class Foo(TimeStampedModel):

    country = CountryField()
```

Answer (score 0):

SmileyChris seems to be pretty busy and unavailable, as the repository hasn't been updated since September. Thankfully, there is a repository that can be forked that is compatible with Django 3 and higher. This can be found here:

https://github.com/yunojuno/django-countries/tree/django-30

It passes all checks for a pull request, however SmileyChris has not responded to the merge request.

To install it just run `pip install git+https://github.com/yunojuno/django-countries.git`

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending forms.Form class then you have to specify .formfield right after your Countryfield and then specify your attributes in formfield() parameter.

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
class CheckOutForm(forms.Form):
    country = CountryField().formfield()
```

But if you are extending from models.Model class then defining Coutryfield is enough.

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
    class CheckOutForm(models.Model):
        country = CountryField()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, instead of trying with models fields such as `ChoiceField` or `CharField` and passing 'choices' as a parameter which contains list of countries as tuple values inside the list created outside in the models.py, Django has compact library to work with selecting country while filling the form.

```
from django-countries.fields import CountryField

class foo(models.Model):
   country = CountryField(blank_label='select country')
   ...
```