# How to set default text for countries on a Django form drop down

Tags: django, forms, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to get this to work and have failed. I've used - help_text, blank_label, default etc which have all resulted in errors. I have a form in which you choose your nationality. The model is working fine and in the admin section too. The countries are being generated using the Django-countries package. However when I render the form the default is Afghanistan. Now, I want to the default to be 'select a country' and then people choose from the drop down. The drop down itself is working beautifully. How do I do this? 
(PS- I've checked various questions here and they dont answer  the question like:
[Django: Country drop down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963930/django-country-drop-down-list), 
[set up form option as default in a drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147575/set-up-form-option-as-default-in-a-drop-down), 
[django countries dropdown default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563354/django-countries-dropdown-default) etc)

as of 31/08/17 I even added Meta which changes the placeholder value. Whilst this has changed the value of other fields it has not affected the countries field. See below for updated code.

From form.py snippet

```
nationality = LazyTypedChoiceField(choices=countries, label='Nationality', required=False)
class Meta:
        model = ProfileTeacher
        fields = ('description', 'document' 'name','last_name','phone_number', 'date_of_birth', 'bank_account', 'id_number', 'postal_code', 'adress', 'profile_image', 'nationality' )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterFormTeacher, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['nationality'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Select a Country'
```

from model.py

```
nationality = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)', null=True, blank = True)
```

Comment: It should be noted that 'blank_label' does not function in the forms, it results in an error.

Comment: Hello! were you able to figure this out? I am also in a similar situation.

Comment: @Animesh nope, I never figured it out.

Comment: @Animesh I just figured it out

Comment: Great! Thank you for getting back to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be rather simple. Within form.py I needed to change it from:

```
nationality = LazyTypedChoiceField(choices=countries, label='Nationality', required=False)
```

to

```
nationality = CountryField(blank_label='(Select country)',).formfield()
```

Within the .formfield() you can then set other attributes like 'required' etc.